# Linux pthread: What does NP mean in PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_READER_NP?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

pthread has several flags, all ends with "NP", just wish to know what "NP" stands for, an abbreviation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "non-portable", which means they are platform specific.

source: https://web.archive.org/web/20090226221922/https://cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-gu.htm

Answer (score 4):

That means "non-portable", and tells you they're platform-specific extensions.